# Unit test an image resize method

Tags: image, symfony, phpunit

Im trying to use PHPUnit in Symfony to test a method which returns a resized image. Ideally, I would be able to mock in image object and set some sizes, then see if the sizes are changed on the return.

The code uses Imagick and decodes the image, Im wondering if this means I will be forced to keep test images on the server for unit testing? Is there a way to mock an image file in code for this purpose?

```
    $based = base64_decode($content);

    if($based){
        $content = $based;
    }

    $imagick = new \Imagick();

    $imagick->readImageBlob($content);
```

If the file were to be stored on the server for testing, how would I mock a request object to include said file?

Comment: You're question implies my question: Is being "forced" to keep images on your server for test purposes somehow a bad thing?

Comment: I suppose not, I just wondered if it was possible to do it with code instead

Comment: seems you want to check if image magick correctly resize your image... Why you don't check only the interaction with a mocked instance of the class `\Imagick()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it, is to mock Imagick, then add files through `readImage` method. Here an example:

```php
class MyClass {
  public function __construct(
    private Imagick $imagick = new Imagick()
  )

  public function doSomething(string $filename)
  {
    $this->imagick->readImage($filename);

    # And blabla...
  }
}
```

And now the test:

```
class MyClassTest extends TestCase {

  public function testShouldDoSomething()
  {
    $imagick = $this->createMock(Imagick::class);
    $imagick->method('readImage')->willReturn(true);

    # And blabla...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the correct way to pass a file to Imagick. It requires `file_get_contents` wrapped in `base64_encode`

```
public function setUp(){
    $imagePath = getcwd()."/src/Woodwork/PartnerBundle/Tests/lin.png";
    $this->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath));
    $logger = $this->getMockBuilder('Logger')->setMethods(array('debug', 'info', 'error'))->getMock();
    $this->imagickHelper = new ImagickHelper($logger);
}
```